# Mvvmlight and Xamarin.iOS unable to find default ctor

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I have a project that is running fine on Android and WinPhone 8. When I attempt to run on iOS, I've getting the following error

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Cannot
>   register: No public constructor found in x

where `x` is whatever `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<T, TU>();` the flow hits first. I've moved the code around (as suggested elsewhere) to ensure all of the platform specific `SimpleIoc` calls are made in `ViewModelLocator`.

I've added public default ctors in the classes that are complaining about the error (I have though set the `PreferredConstructor` to the original, not the newly added public ctor).

I have a feeling that this error is a false positive (something else is failing, but pointing at that code).

Using Xam.iOS via a build server (the code is coming from VS2015). Xcode is running the 8.3 emulators (it may need updating to allow for 8.4 testing)

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the Linker is optimising away the constructor, if it thinks it's not used. Try setting the Linker Options to "Don't Link" and see if it does it again, or even new-up an instance of the class elsewhere so that the Linker knows that the constructor is used. You don't necessarily want to leave it that way, but if it eliminates the error, you'll at least know the reason.

Comment: Add the [Preserve] attribute on the default constructor to prevent the linker from optimizing it await.

Comment: @Steve Morgan,

Tried the linker options to "Don't Link" still its crashing..
I am trying to run iPhone distribution build on my iPhone 

I am uploading my ipa on app store and using Test-Flight downloading the ipa and trying to run app is crashing immediately...
If I Runs my app on simulator it works fine only for distribution build its causing this issue


Any Suggestion will be appropriated..

Answer (score 0):

The **[Preserve]** attribute did the trick for me.
Decorate constructor with it and keep your linker settings.

This attribute is part of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices namespace.